# Undefined character while parsing turkish in Blackberry 9700

Tags: blackberry, xml-parsing

I am parsing some turkish response from the web service.It parse successfully in Blackberry torch and 8520 but while coming to Blackberry 9700 its not working it show some undefined characters in text.I am not understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

> RightClick on "ProjectName"-->properties-->Resource-->Text file encoding-->click on "Other" radio button and select **"UTF-8"**;

build the project and run it;

Comment: i am already set encoding to utf-8 while parsing like ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8"))

Comment: comment that and try this once;
Because if you do like that it works for entire application; means another place you are using data;

Comment: ok thank you but its works in my phone but in my client phone its not working so have to wait for his response

Comment: If you give down vote, provide reason otherwise don't do that;

Answer (score 0):

Does the 9700 have Turkish fonts installed?  See if you can switch the device locale to Turkish.

Comment: how can i check whether it supports or not